# React Component returning "TypeError: undefined has no properties"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component right below which is later used inside another component in react.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="media">
          <div className="media-left media-middle">
            <a href="#no"><img className="media-object" src={this.props.image} alt="" /></a>
          </div>
          <div className="media-body"><span className="pull-right">{this.props.name}</span>
            <h4 className="media-heading">{this.props.title}</h4>
            {this.props.desc}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  desc: PropTypes.string,
};

export default MyComponent;

//Then on other component

import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './mycomponent.component';

<MyComponent
  title="Title Here"
  name="Some Name"
  desc="Description here"
  image="http://placehold.it/100x100"
/>
```

The problem is that it's not rendering and the developer console is returning the following error:

**"TypeError: undefined has no properties"**

What is the problem here and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to include the `props` argument to the function and use `props.foo` instead of `this.props.foo`.

Comment: Its a `stateless functional component`, `this` keyword will be not available inside this, as well as you need to receive the `props` as an `function` argument, check the stackoverflow doc on `Stateless Functional Component`: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/6588/stateless-functional-components#t=201704182033478707844

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass in props to `MyComponent` like so:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
     console.log("example prop is", props.image);
);
```

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis bro!

Comment: And here I was thinking that my rebellious ways would go unnoticed. The missing parenthesis has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. This was caused because the initial array was defined as an empty array `[]` . This will make react to define it as `undefined` which will cause the problem. Instead you can initialize the array with a random element and then replace it when you set state.

In my case I was using -

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userdata:[], /* Notice that the array is empty*/
   };


  responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({userdata: response});
  }
```

I changed it to

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userdata:['Hello'], /* Notice that the array has an initial element*/
   };


  responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({userdata: response});
  }
```

I am not really sure what the issue was but using an initial element solved the problem